# Rails 4 - jQuery animate rotate - almost functional

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, animation, rotation

I found an extremely useful bit of code that allows you to animate the rotation of an element, and while it almost works perfectly for me, the result is jumpy.

```
$.fn.animateRotate = function(angle, duration, easing, complete) {
    var args = $.speed(duration, easing, complete);
    var step = args.step;
    return this.each(function(i, e) {
        args.complete = $.proxy(args.complete, e);
        args.step = function(now) {
            $.style(e, 'transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
            if (step) return step.apply(e, arguments);
        };

        $({deg: 0}).animate({deg: angle}, args);
    });
};

$(".glyphicon-remove").on("click", function() {
    $(this).animateRotate(45, 1000);
    preventDefault();
});
```

As seen in my jsFiddle, the rotation works, but upon clicking the button a second time, the element doesn't simply rotate again, it is first reset, and then it rotates.

How can I prevent this "reset" from occurring?

https://jsfiddle.net/rnqzdLc9/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store the current desired angle as a start value for next clicks :

```
$.fn.animateRotate = function(angle,prevAngle, duration, easing, complete) {
    var args = $.speed(duration, easing, complete);
    var step = args.step;
    return this.each(function(i, e) {
        args.complete = $.proxy(args.complete, e);
        args.step = function(now) {
            $.style(e, 'transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
            if (step) return step.apply(e, arguments);
        };

        $({deg: prevAngle}).animate({deg: angle}, args);
    });
};
var angle = 0;
var prevAngle = 0

$(".glyphicon-remove").on("click", function(e) {
    prevAngle = angle
    angle +=45;
    $(this).animateRotate(angle, prevAngle, 1000);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5x382vrn/)

---

First create vars, including the new one `prevAngle`:

```
var angle = 0;
var prevAngle = 0
```

---

`prevAngle`get the `angle` value before incrementing it:

```
prevAngle = angle
angle +=45;
```

---

Send/Get prevAngle to the animateRotate function :

```
$(this).animateRotate(angle, prevAngle, 1000);
```

And

```
$.fn.animateRotate = function(angle,prevAngle, duration, easing, complete) {
...
}
```

---

And finally animate rotation from the `prevAngle` value :

```
$({deg: prevAngle}).animate({deg: angle}, args);
```